# Need help on to make svg image into 3d object

Tags: modeling

I have imported by SVG object build through inkscape and trying to convert into 3d object, but object looks like as attached here
[image]

What next steps I should take to make it nice 3d object with 2-3 mm thick and how i would need to clear those lines in between or appearing on the object face?

Want to understand what are those and why do they appear and what's the best practice to follow, while creating svg images for 3d objects?

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Since you imported curve object, just go to Curve Properties and change Geometry > Extrude value ... you dont have to necessarily convert  into a mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Select all in *Edit* mode and press *X > limited Dissolve*. You can tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box on the bottom left of the 3D view. To extrude, keep everything selected and press *E*, drag in order to get thickness.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing wanted to under how to get the smooth surface print?, currently its like a lines on the surface.

Comment: maybe try right click > Shade Smooth then in the Object Data panel > Normals > Auto Smooth and play with the value. If it still doesn't work please share your file?